# best practice for deploying file shares in Remote Desktop Services

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, azure, file-sharing, terminal-server

We are setting up a new virtual Remote Desktop Services deployment for 10 users in Azure, with 2 domain controllers and 2 RDS servers. Our requirement is to have resilient and fast file system for users to work in this environment, and to easily have access to files locally on their laptops (many Macs). All servers are running 2012 R2 Server.

We are considering two options for files in RDS environment: configuring 2 VM file servers with DFS on the same domain, or setting up DFS directly on the RDS servers, which will give users fast local access to files, and still provide redundancy. Does anyone have a better suggestion how to achieve this?

We are also unsure about which file sharing solution is enterprise ready, as in the future we would like to implement approval workflows for when files are shared with 3rd parties.

Any insights are most welcome

Comment: Don't put data on rds server is a best practice . Why ? because rds are like app server , only here to to a job , rendering and running apps . If you really want a easy to maintain/upgrade/scale your solution use : windows share from a file server (with or without dfs betwen your file server) and network drive for user in rdp session , printer setup with local port on server

Comment: If you can hold off a bit Azure Files would be a good solution for the 1st part. The 2nd part is a little broad, as pretty much anything can be shared one way or another

Comment: YuKYuK: thanks for recommending file servers, this is one of two choices and we just want to get community feedback
Drifter104: We tried Azure Files, but it seems tit has only one set of credentials for the whole share, it did not have the granularity for setting up individual Windows user accounts rights.  Also as it was a share, it would not perform as well as a local VM disk, where we also have the option for using SSD storage. So we counted out Azure File shares for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

If RDS APPS, I would recommend a second partition and then use that for DFS on each RDS Server.

If you are giving full desktop environment I wouldn't suggest sharing those roles, although you CAN, just be sure to prefer NTFS Permissions over share permissions.

Roles that are against recommendations to combine would be RDS and AD. For most of my smaller customers, they would have 2 servers:

Primary - Active Directory, DNS, DHCP, RRAS/VPN, NPS, and Exchange

Secondary - Network Shares, Printers, and RDS Apps.

Otherwise adding more dedicated servers is always best.

Answer (score -2):

If you have Office365 subscription, perhaps it includes OneDrive for Business.

Comment: Azure subscriptions do not include OneDrive for Business.

Comment: meant Office365